# windows 7 Downloaded jpg Unblock security warning

Tags: internet-explorer-10

Issue just started - downloaded images not showing up using IE10 and IE11 after the downloaded jpg Unblock button is clicked.

IE10 shows downloaded jpg, ONLY, when the Unblock button IS NOT clicked.

Images are visible with Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome, for both, unblock clicked and unblock not clicked.

I used msconfig to troubleshoot issue to no avail. Restored back to time when there was no issue and the problem was there, also. Ran windows in safemode and still had issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Ralph

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this issue.

Because the images weren't showing up I always concentrated on them, individually.

However, I just discovered, for example, when I clicked on my index.htm I got the ubiqtous security Unblock msg
and when I clicked unblock and ran it under IE10 all my images were visible.

All the files I was using were downloaded from a site and consequently they all were marked with the Unblock msg.

For all images to be visible check all folders and files properties and make sure they each have been unblocked individually.

Ralph